# Webapp integration in Firefox doesnt show

Tags: firefox, webapps

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I don't see the Unity section in Firefox preferences](https://askubuntu.com/questions/172966/i-dont-see-the-unity-section-in-firefox-preferences)

In Firefox the webapp integration doesnt show. in chrome it does. I also have no unity tab in my firefox preferences.

Comment: Which version is this?

Comment: Are you running the latest packages? Are you on Quantal or Precise?

Comment: Im running 12.10 64bit up to date, firefox 15.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem by installing [xul-ext-unity [image: Install xul-ext-unity]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/xul-ext-unity).