# I don't see the Unity section in Firefox preferences

Tags: unity, webapps

I found in another question on AskUbuntu someone had demonstrated on how to enable/disable sites that would integrate with Unity, in the webapps preview.
There was a screenshot showing a "Unity" section in the Firefox preferences.
I don't have that option.
This is the screenshot:

[image]

How can I get this option? Is there any package I need?

This is the original question containing the screenshot: [How to manage "Unity WebApps Chromium extension" different options?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/169282/how-to-manage-unity-webapps-chromium-extension-different-options)

Comment: It isn't available now.. Looking around

Answer (score 5):

The desktop integration options are now located in the "General" section of the preference pane in Firefox, at the bottom "Desktop Integration".

[image: Desktop integration settings in Firefox]

Comment: +1.. Add a screenshot just to be sure. :-)

Comment: Desktop integration settings image added

Comment: In the latest version of the extension, the Desktop Integration section is at the top. However, it still does not offer an option for disabling a particular site.

Comment: The window will only list websites you do not want to be asked to integrate into webapps. It's useless for webapps management/removing. You can hardly even call it 'options'. It's nothing but 'exceptions'. To remove specific webapps integration see http://askubuntu.com/questions/216725/how-can-i-remove-web-apps-not-thewhole-feature-but-certain-web-apps

Comment: It also does not seem to work properly - the overall preferences is not persisted, so you cannot turn it off completely. I've seen the preferences move from top to bottom too.

Answer (score 3):

I had [a similar question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/172965/webapp-integration-in-firefox-doesnt-show). I installed [xul-ext-unity [image: Install xul-ext-unity]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/xul-ext-unity). That fixed my problem.