# How can I remove web-apps?

Tags: unity, software-center, webapps, software-uninstall

How can I remove web-apps? (Not the whole feature, but certain web-apps)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Simple, just use:

```
sudo apt-get remove unity-webapps-*appidontlike*
```

i.e.

```
sudo apt-get remove unity-webapps-twitter
```

Examples:

```
unity-webapps-amazoncloudreader - Unity Webapp for AmazonCloudReader
unity-webapps-angrybirds - Unity Webapp for AngryBirds
unity-webapps-bbcnews - Unity Webapp for BBCNews
unity-webapps-cuttherope - Unity Webapp for CutTheRope
unity-webapps-facebookapps - Unity Webapp for FacebookApps
unity-webapps-facebookmessenger - Unity Webapp for FacebookMessenger
unity-webapps-gmail - Unity Webapp for GMail
unity-webapps-googlecalendar - Unity Webapp for GoogleCalendar
unity-webapps-googledocs - Unity Webapp for GoogleDocs
unity-webapps-googleplus - Unity Webapp for GooglePlus
unity-webapps-grooveshark - Unity Webapp for grooveshark
unity-webapps-hulu-player - Unity Webapp for hulu-player
unity-webapps-lastfm-radio - Unity Webapp for lastfm-radio
unity-webapps-launchpad - Unity Webapp for Launchpad
unity-webapps-librefm - Unity Webapp for LibreFm
unity-webapps-linkedin - Unity Webapp for LinkedIn
unity-webapps-livemail - Unity Webapp for LiveMail
unity-webapps-mail-ru - Unity Webapp for mail-ru
unity-webapps-newsblur - Unity Webapp for Newsblur
unity-webapps-pandora-com - Unity Webapp for pandora-com
unity-webapps-qq-mail - Unity Webapp for qq-mail
unity-webapps-reddit - Unity Webapp for Reddit
unity-webapps-tumblr - Unity Webapp for Tumblr
unity-webapps-twitter - Unity Webapp for Twitter
unity-webapps-vkcom - Unity Webapp for Vkcom
unity-webapps-wordpress-com - Unity Webapp for wordpress-com
unity-webapps-yahoomail - Unity Webapp for YahooMail
unity-webapps-yahoonews - Unity Webapp for YahooNews
unity-webapps-yandex-music - Unity Webapp for yandex-music
unity-webapps-yandexnews - Unity Webapp for YandexNews
unity-webapps-youtube - Unity Webapp for YouTube
```

Each web app is its own package. I don't think any of them are dependent on each other, so you shouldn't have any issues uninstalling ones you don't need/use.

The Amazon and Ubuntu One Web Apps seem to be baked in to the web apps application, so you cannot remove these by simply uninstalling the package. The easiest way to remove these is to install [Unsettings](http://www.florian-diesch.de/software/unsettings/). This is a tweak tool, similar to Ubuntu Tweak. It is not available in the repos, so you have to install its PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:diesch/testing
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install unsettings
```

Now that you installed it, fire it up and select the "Web apps" tab on the left side. To disable a web app, simply move the websites that use it from either Pre-authorized or Enabled to Disabled, then click the apply button (the little gears).

Comment: I'd especially like to remove amazon. But `sudo apt-get remove unity-webapps-amazon` doesn't work.
`

Comment: I didn't realize that Amazon and Ubuntu One were built-in to the web apps application. I updated my answer with specific information on removing these two webapps.

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help.

Comment: Terminal for webapps integration management?! Ubuntu team: **Pathetic!** @reverendj1: What about the omgubuntu.co.uk webapp integration?

Comment: @Bucic The ombubuntu.co.uk webapp isn't a default web app, so uninstall it with whatever method you used to install it in the first place. On the other hand, using Unsetting can disable any webapps, no matter how they were installed, so you can go that route too.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:  Whoops, posted on wrong question.  Got here trying to remove the Amazon app in 16.04.  Cross linking to [How to remove the Unity Amazon package in 16.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760204/how-to-remove-the-unity-amazon-package-in-16-04)

If you want to remove all of them and the generic Browser app, try this. Open the Ubuntu Software app, find the "Browser" app and click remove.

Comment: Youre aware that you can delete your own answers :) ? No offense meant just trying to keep the site clear