# Where do webapps install after accepting them

Tags: webapps

I am trying to find where do webapps install after accepting them with Firefox. This can help me when I want to eliminate one of them or edit something.

Comment: I think it is already installes, You are just allowing it to execute

Comment: [This](http://askubuntu.com/questions/216725/how-can-i-remove-web-apps-not-thewhole-feature-but-certain-web-apps) should answer your question about removing certain ones.  You can view them in software center too.

Comment: @iSeth - Thanks, still I want to know where they install. This way, when the misbehave I can kill them... silently...with no pain...^^

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are many ways to find this information.

**1) You can find it by opening the .deb that installs them.**

As an example, I pick the .deb of youtube's one from here: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/quantal/i386/unity-webapps-youtube/2.4.10
Open it with archive manager, then look for the file DEBIAN/md5sums and open it with a text editor.
It is

```
d5bbca2bb83fe5cc16a92e35bf75b26f  usr/share/doc/unity-webapps-youtube/changelog.gz
a4b9f911211d21db51342de237b5dc5c  usr/share/doc/unity-webapps-youtube/copyright
c571c6d100d418b65bcacbb4f78d46d6  usr/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps/unity-webapps-youtube.png
0d55340014577968398aab8fcee7409c  usr/share/icons/unity-webapps-applications/128/apps/unity-webapps-youtube.png
c571c6d100d418b65bcacbb4f78d46d6  usr/share/icons/unity-webapps-applications/48/apps/unity-webapps-youtube.png
0e95c345e7aa4a96ac76a94df2c0071a  usr/share/icons/unity-webapps-applications/52/apps/unity-webapps-youtube.png
a7d678d599978f9ac7bffe36d776558c  usr/share/icons/unity-webapps-applications/64/apps/unity-webapps-youtube.png
58beafe67c7b136d0f157c963445c514  usr/share/unity-webapps/userscripts/unity-webapps-youtube/YouTube.user.js
5f8d5ce54c5a7c7c4cca88d5691beedd  usr/share/unity-webapps/userscripts/unity-webapps-youtube/manifest.json
```

This are the files installed with the webapp.

**2) As an alternative you can use** `apt-file`

By using simply

```
$ apt-file show unity-webapps-youtube 
unity-webapps-youtube: /usr/share/doc/unity-webapps-youtube/changelog.gz
unity-webapps-youtube: /usr/share/doc/unity-webapps-youtube/copyright
unity-webapps-youtube: /usr/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps/unity-webapps-youtube.png
unity-webapps-youtube: /usr/share/icons/unity-webapps-applications/128/apps/unity-webapps-youtube.png
unity-webapps-youtube: /usr/share/icons/unity-webapps-applications/48/apps/unity-webapps-youtube.png
unity-webapps-youtube: /usr/share/icons/unity-webapps-applications/52/apps/unity-webapps-youtube.png
unity-webapps-youtube: /usr/share/icons/unity-webapps-applications/64/apps/unity-webapps-youtube.png
unity-webapps-youtube: /usr/share/unity-webapps/userscripts/unity-webapps-youtube/YouTube.user.js
unity-webapps-youtube: /usr/share/unity-webapps/userscripts/unity-webapps-youtube/manifest.json
```

**3) You can achieve the same by using** `dpkg -L`

Note that this will work only if the package is already installed.

Anyhow, I don't really know how you can use this informations to kill them ;)

Comment: Very complete answer dadexix86.