# How to remove the Unity Amazon package in 16.04?

Tags: unity, launcher, 16.04, amazon

I was able to go to the ubuntu software center before and remove it and now it doesn't show up since the switch to the gnome software store. Trying the terminal method of removing the shopping lens doesn't work in this release.

[image]

Comment: I can remove it running apt-get remove unity-webapps-common but unity tweak tool needs this package too.

Comment: The shopping lens is not installed in 16.04 by default. The Amazon icon you see is the web app. Searching in the dash will not invoke it.

Comment: Back in Ubuntu 12.04 days I thought they talked about ditching this spyware/marketware crap. Canonical is insane. I was disgusted to see Amazon in my unity launcher once I got a brand new 16.04 machine. So sad that the first step in each Ubuntu install is to remove junk like this!

Comment: I like the solution by Reinier Post the most.

Comment: If google sends you here and you have 18.04, the answer is simple: `sudo apt remove ubuntu-web-launchers` (run `dpkg -L ubuntu-web-launchers` first if you want to see what's in it--100% Amazon)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Removing the `unity-webapps-common` package removes Amazon from the dash. Since the Amazon webapp is part of that package, you can't just remove the Amazon portion (well, short of editing the source code). This is a problem when other programs (like Unity Tweak Tool) depend on that package.

As noted by fitojb in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/262255/11317) to another question, however, this command will prevent the Amazon icon from showing up in the dash:

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/share/applications/ubuntu-amazon-default.desktop
```

However, as dobey pointed out in a comment below, when the `unity-webapps-common` package updates the file will be replaced and the command will have to be run again. A more permanent method is to copy the .desktop file to your local applications directory and then add a line to the file to prevent it from showing up in the dash:

```
echo 'Hidden=true' | cat /usr/share/applications/ubuntu-amazon-default.desktop - > ~/.local/share/applications/ubuntu-amazon-default.desktop
```

Comment: No. That is the wrong way to hide the app. It will re-appear again if/when there is an update to the unity-webapps-common package, or it gets reinstalled for some reason. Copying the file to `~/.local/share/applications/` and adding the line `Hidden=true` to the end of it, should actually hide it.

Comment: I have done the 2nd "solution" as how I understand it this should overwrite the icon and make it invisible. **But it does not work in ubuntu 16.10**

Comment: In Ubuntu 17.10,  .desktop file is:  /usr/share/applications/com.canonical.launcher.amazon.desktop

Answer (score 14):

As Aibara Iduas suggests, removing `/usr/share/applications/ubuntu-amazon-default.desktop` is the solution. But it will come back with the next upgrade. The solution to copy the file to `~/.local/share/applications/ubuntu-amazon-default.desktop` works only for the current user. To disable this .desktop file for all users on the machine, and to prevent upgrades from putting it back, the solution is to divert the file with `dpkg-divert`.

```
sudo dpkg-divert \
  --divert /usr/share/applications/ubuntu-amazon-default.desktop.diverted \
  --local \
  --rename \
  /usr/share/applications/ubuntu-amazon-default.desktop
```

Comment: Alternatively, put the `rm -rf /usr/share/applications/ubuntu-amazon-default.desktop` command into a script then run it every so often via cron. Works in Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 6):

In Ubuntu 18.04, just deinstall the `ubuntu-web-launchers` package:

```
sudo apt remove ubuntu-web-launchers
```

It only contains the Amazon launcher, as you can see by doing

```
dpkg -L ubuntu-web-launchers
```

first.

Comment: This was really useful. How did you find this out?

Comment: I probably used `locate` to find relevant files and `dpkg -S` on a few of them to determine relevant package names.

Comment: This should be voted up as this is a better solutions with later versions of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 5):

The dash still requires the old ubuntu software center to uninstall programs, even though it is not included with 16.04. Install the `software-center` package and log out and back in to your account and then you will be able to view screenshots of programs and uninstall them by right clicking on them in the dash like in previous versions.

Answer (score 1):

You just click on the app then drag it into the trash (it work for me).

Answer (score 1):

For me worked this on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS:

```
cd /usr/share/applications
mv ubuntu-amazon-default.desktop ../~ubuntu-amazon-default.desktop
```

Answer (score 1):

To avoid installing apps to unintall the app, I did it manually (in Ubuntu 16):

```
sudo rm /usr/share/applications/ubuntu-amazon-default.desktop
sudo rm /usr/share/unity-webapps/userscripts/unity-webapps-amazon/Amazon.user.js
sudo rm /usr/share/unity-webapps/userscripts/unity-webapps-amazon/manifest.json
```

If it is surreptitiously installed again, just run it again, or put it in a cleanup script you run when you update your OS.

Source:
https://www.lifewire.com/remove-amazon-application-from-ubuntu-4134329

Answer (score 0):

**Attention: this solution propably only works if you have upgraded from 15.10 to 16.04 LTS**

Thats pretty easy now, press <kbd>windows/superkey</kbd>. In bash enter amazon to find the amazon software.

Right click it and see the detailed information, where you shalt find an incredible remove button :)

Have fun.

Comment: I just see "launch" in the dash window. I'm on 16.04 btw.

Comment: Im aswell on 16.04, and this since two weeks. *Entfernen* means remove in english

Comment: This is from a clean install. Not sure why they made it impossible to remove this but i guess I will have to live with it for now or switch to another *buntu :[

Comment: Well i will comment on this here if i find a solution, you got me going now. And ok that could possibly be the reason, i had upgraded from 15.10 to beta release.

Comment: Thanks for the persistence. If I come across anything  i'll make sure to update as well. It did just get released so i'm sure someone will figure it out soon.

Answer (score -1):

[How can I remove Unity web apps?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/214755/how-can-i-remove-unity-web-apps)
-> Try:

```
sudo apt-get remove unity-webapps-amazon*
```

Can't say it's the solution, because first thing I did, was search "amazon" files and manualy deleted  "/usr/share/unity-webapps/userscripts/unity-webapps-amazon/" *(no this it didn't remove Amazon)* and now the apt-get wont find the Amazon.

Comment: That doesn't work in 16.04. The only package that fits that description is `unity-webapps-amazoncloudread`, which, if removed, does nothing.