# How do you remove the Amazon app in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: uninstall, 16.04, amazon

In previous versions you could remove the Amazon app via the Ubuntu Software application, under "uncategorised". But in 16.04 I can't find it there, so how do I get rid of it.

Thank you please.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove the Unity Amazon package in 16.04?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/760204/how-to-remove-the-unity-amazon-package-in-16-04)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't worry you can remove/dissable it from command line.

Try this first,

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Lenses disabled-scopes "['more_suggestions-amazon.scope', 'more_suggestions-u1ms.scope', 'more_suggestions-populartracks.scope', 'music-musicstore.scope', 'more_suggestions-ebay.scope', 'more_suggestions-ubuntushop.scope', 'more_suggestions-skimlinks.scope']"
```

if above not works for you , try followng,

```
sudo apt-get remove unity-webapps-common
```