# Crash after every shutdown in grub when starting ubuntu

Tags: boot, nvidia, lenovo, 17.10, crash

I am using an Lenovo Yoga 720, and I am experiencing crashes after each shutdown. To explain it further...

I shut down the computer and it works properly. When I try to boot after that shutdown the computer freezes after choosing to boot ubuntu in grub.

I am able to proceed by turning the computer of with the power button and boot again. This time everything work as intented. I disabled `silent splash` so you should see output from grub in terminal, but on a failed boot, I never get to the terminal.

Has anyone experienced this behaviour before?

Background info:

- Lenovo Yoga 720: 7700hq,
- 16 gb ram,
- 500gb harddrive,
- Geforce 1050.

I use dualboot with Windows 10 and ubuntu 17.10 with kernel 4.14

since it's the kernel with working trackpad drivers for my computer. I have also installed the proprietary nvidia drivers, which solved the `unable to shutdown` problem many users faced.

I've followed [the answer from rubo77 in this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/946480/installing-ubuntu-alongside-windows-on-lenovo-yoga-720) to install ubuntu 17.10 from a fellow user.

I've tried the journalctl -b1 to see if there was anything from the boot but it does not exist.

Comment: After having shutdown linux, do you use Windows in between or direct boot to linux again which then results in the crash? In addition: removing `splash quiet` from grub might add some details to the boot process and could help diagnosing the problem.

Comment: I disabled splash quiet and I saw when I tried this again, and I now saw that it is grub I\m stuck in. I`ve edited the question.

Comment: I do not start windows between the startups.

Comment: How do you shutdown? Do you see the same behavior if you shutdown using `sudo shutdown -h now`?

Comment: did you run `sudo update-grub` after removing the `silent splash` option?

Comment: I used the normal shutdown and shutdown in terminal. I tried -h and it's the same behaviour.

Comment: Yes, I ran sudo update-grub. I see the terminal on a successful boot.

Comment: @duffe do you have any more ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing bootparameters in Ubuntu Grub](https://askubuntu.com/questions/991270/changing-bootparameters-in-ubuntu-grub)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See answer at this post: [Changing bootparameters in Ubuntu Grub](https://askubuntu.com/questions/991270/changing-bootparameters-in-ubuntu-grub)

The problem was solved by changing boot parameters in grub.