# Changing bootparameters in Ubuntu Grub

Tags: grub2, 17.10

|

My PC wont boot every second time I try to boot ubuntu. But I seem to have found a fix, which is editing setparams by pressing 'e' in grub.

I edit the

```
"gfxmode #linux_gfx_mode"
```

to

```
"gfxmode nomodeset"
```

and can then boot ubuntu as normal. So I wanted to make this change permanent. I tried changing grub command in the /etc/default/grub with

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nomodeset"
```

This is added to the **linux** boot command in setparams in the grub, but makes my computer hang up instead and does not change the line with

```
"gfxmode #linux_gfx_mode"
```

How do I make change the gfxmode permanent so my computer can boot properly every time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` is generated from files in `/etc/grub.d`

I managed to make the change permanent by replacing in this file `/etc/grub.d/10_linux` the line:

```
echo "  gfxmode \$linux_gfx_mode" | sed "s/^/$submenu_indentation/"
```

with this:

```
echo "  gfxmode nomodeset" | sed "s/^/$submenu_indentation/"
```

Afterwards I ran:

```
sudo update-grub
```

to generate the new `grub.cfg`

Comment: Will test this as soon as possible! Looks good so I will mark this as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood the question, you have to modify the file /etc/default/grub (do it as root) and then give the command:

```
sudo update-grub
```

This command makes the change effective

Comment: I already did it. What I mean is, that when I change the line gfxmode in grub, it works, but not when I add it to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT. Do you know why?

Comment: I would modify in the  same way the line: GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
 This line are for the general parameters, taken also by the recovery mode. If you are launching a recovery mode you need to modify that. 
Also remember to update grub

Comment: This still just adds it to the Linux command line in the grub parameters.  It does not give any other result than what I tried

Comment: It only works when I edit the "gfx mode" line. Nowhere else. Is there a way to change it permanently?

Answer (score 0):

I have edited `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` and modified `"gfxmode #linux_gfx_mode"`  to `"gfxmode nomodeset"` in the bootparameters for ubuntu. I know this may not be the correct way to do it, but it seems to be the only way. I will have to do this every time I update grub.

Is there another way to make it permanent, please leave a better suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

After reading the script in `/etc/grub.d/10_linux`, I have found a better answer than the [currently accepted one](https://askubuntu.com/a/994013/1177565). Simply add this line to your `/etc/default/grub` file, and then run `sudo update-grub`:

```
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX="nomodeset"
```

This variable is what ultimately controls the code path mentioned in the other answer, and appears to be the correct way to modify this setting. Additionally, you may want to change

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="splash quiet"
```

to this instead

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nosplash nomodeset"
```