# Lenovo yoga 720 13lkb 2 in 1 touchscreen auto rotation

Tags: keyboard, lenovo, touchscreen

I have the Lenovo yoga 720 13" 2017. I installed ubuntu 17.10 after changing bios settings (SSD controller to AHCI and UEFI to legacy) as advised [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/946480/installing-ubuntu-alongside-windows-on-lenovo-yoga-720). Install is working correctly and even trackpad works out-of-the-box.

I have an issue with the touchscreen not rotating when I switch to tablet mode, however - I was able to get it working by running the command:

```
watch -n 0.1 cat '/sys/bus/iio/devices/iio:device'*/*raw*
```

So my question is how do I get this command to run in the background on boot.
Plus it would be nice if I would be able to present the on-screen keyboard when the physicl keyboard is disabled, it gets disabled but only when I flip it a full 360 degrees but not when I am using tent mode. And the on-screen keyboard is coming up every time I am touching the screen - I had to use gnome extension - Block caribou, but it disables the touch keyboard completely.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you solved it already, but I had the same problem on my Yoga520. According to https://github.com/hadess/iio-sensor-proxy/issues/160 there is a fix in Linux kernel >= 4.13.3 while Ubuntu 17.10 is on 4.13.0 by default.

I got the sensor to function out of the box by upgrading the kernel to 4.15.4. I followed: https://fossbytes.com/install-upgrade-linux-kernel-ubuntu-mint-ukuu/

Let me know if you can get the ambient light sensor / fingerprint sensor working