# Failed to start Cryptography Setup for cryptswap1

Tags: nvidia, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

Since yesterday installing the `bumblebee-nvidia` package I cannot boot into my Ubuntu 17.10 Desktop any more.

I get this error:

```
[FAILED] Failed to start Cryptography Setup for cryptswap1.
See 'systemctl status systemd-cryptsetup@cryptswap1.service' for details.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for dev-mapper-cryptswap1.device.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for Encrypted Volumes.
```

and then the system hangs.

This might be related to [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1731870).
I cannot access any console to look in neither systemctl service output, nor logs, by that time. how can I fix this?

Here a photo of the boot screen:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I entered the root console from the grub rescue-kernel and then

1. I removed the package `bumblebee-nvidia` which didn't help alone.
2. I commented out (with a `#` at the start of the line) the line

   ```
   cryptswap1 /target/swapfile /dev/urandom swap,offset=1024,cipher=aes-xts-plain64
   ```

   in `/etc/crypttab` and

   ```
   /dev/mapper/cryptswap1                                 none                    swap    sw              0       0
   ```

   in `/etc/fstab`

After the first reboot this helped. after another reboot I ran into the same freeze again!

Then I removed the NVIDIA-Driver in the GUI for advanced drivers and added a swapfile instead of encryptedswap. This seems to solve the issue (but as a drawback has no encrypted swap any more)

Comment: Does bumblebee-nvidia install & work ok now? It doesn't seem related to an encrypted swapfile

Comment: I am afraid to try that again. Do I need that package? See comments in https://askubuntu.com/a/963767/34298